# Flex SWF not running after bring out from the Flex builder

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have developed a flex project

It brings out the result from an xml file through an url.

It works when i run from flex builder..

I had made a copy of swf file of that mxml file and run seperately by keeping in my desktop..
No values are fetched from the url... What is the solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting the security sandbox in Flex.  Either put the SWF on the same host as the data that it is requesting or setup a proxy on the server the SWF is on to forward requests to the server with the data.

Flex Builder automatically adds apps to the trusted sandbox so that you don't see errors when you make network requests.